# Update input field when typing

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

I just started today with Node.js and Socket.io . Now I'd like to update the value of an input field. I've spend my whole day so far looking for something to do this with. I'd greatly appreciate it if you guys could help me out with this since I don't know where to start.

Comment: put some code or if you want reference check socketio samples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how does your code look like?
Are you talking about the value attribute of your input field?

If I understand you right. Thats just one line of code you need to add.

```
document.getElementById("inputfieldid").value = "new value";
```

EDIT: Then I'd try something like that. 
I didn't test it. But if you type something in your input field it should directly send an update message to the server. 
At your server the socket.on('update'... will listen to new input.

```
  // server.js
  var express = require('express');
  var app = express();
  var io = require('socket.io')(server);

  var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
      var port = server.address().port;
      console.log('Server running at port %s', port);
  });

  io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.emit('onconnected', { message: 'connected'});

    socket.on('update', function(data) {
      console.log("new Value: "+data.value);
    });
  });


  // client.js
  const socket = require('socket.io-client')(`${config.SERVERURL}:${config.PORT}`);

  socket.on('onconnected', function(data){
    console.log(data);
  });

  document.getElementById("inputfieldid").addEventListener("change",update);
  function update(e){
    socket.emit('update',{
      value: e.target.value
    });
  }
```

I hope it will help

Comment: EvilBurrito I would like to add this:
if the value of the input fields changed, then send the data to the server.js. Then in de server.js i would like to listen for data and if the data is there, then send the data to the other client. I guess the client needs a listener too. But i dont know where to start :(

Comment: Oh and if there are still problems. 
Really take a look at the socket.io website. They have many examples. This might be useful for you as well https://socket.io/get-started/chat/